# gRPC C++ async client completion queue drain

Tags: c++, grpc

I have created an gRPC async client written in C++ which makes both streaming and unary requests to a server, using a completion queue.

In the destructor of the client class the `Shutdown` method of the completion queue is called, then I thought I could call `Next` to drain the queue and obtain the pending tags, but instead the call to `Next` blocks everything.

The pending tags are needed since they are objects create with `new` and must be deleted to avoid leaks.

What is the correct way to drain a queue used for an async client?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be that 1 tag into the completion queue, 1 tag out, so all the pending ops will get their tags returned from Next (even if the RPC gets canceled).

The symptom that Next blocks is likely due to there are pending events that is not finished.

You may like to use TryCancel to terminate the call quickly

Comment: Thanks! That actually worked. My problem was that I was trying to shut down the queue while an infinite stream was being read from the server. Calling `context->TryCancel();` before `cq->Shutdown();` made `Next` non blocking.